# JQuery not adjusting image src in IE and Firefox, only in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I've created an image gallery which works as expected in Chrome, but does not work at all in firefox or internet explorer. I've had a look around at some similar questions but I don't believe they are especially helpful in solving this issue.

I've created a JFiddle of the code:

https://jsfiddle.net/ydmgjzwp/

I'm guessing the code which is causing the issue is:

```
function updateMainImage(){
  var selected = imageController.selectedImageObject;
  var currentImageObject = imageController.imageObjects[selected];
  var newImage = currentImageObject.image;

  $(imageController.mainImageImg).attr("src", newImage);
}
```

In IE and FF the main image at the top does not load at all. It ought to be changed, via JQuery, to the first of the smaller images, and then whichever the user selects.

I haven't noticed anything too useful in the console logs, but again I may be missing something. Any help that anyone can offer is VERY much appreciated.

Comment: You have double quote on the img src url - inspect the html code.

Comment: Thanks, I think that is what is causing the problem. Right now I'm trying to figure out where the double quotes are coming from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace this function

```
function trimCssUrlSyntax(inputString) {
                    var returnString = inputString.replace('")', '');
                    returnString = returnString.replace('url("', '');
                    return returnString;
                }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me, as I believe replace needs to arguments?

Comment: I have this working now - however, it did require one extra part to get it working. I added: returnString = returnString.replace(/"/g, ''); before the function returned in order to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

You have double quotes on your image src. I change your function and works.

```
function trimCssUrlSyntax(inputString){
      var returnString = inputString.replace(")", );
      returnString =  returnString.replace("url(", );
      return returnString;
    }
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/ydmgjzwp/2/)**

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't seem to work for me; without a second argument, I understand replace will insert undefined